# Drag and Drop files uploading error php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i watched many links on internet and also reffered to each and every question related to this topic but none helped! so plz any1 check this code and tell me where i'm doing wrong?

html code:

```
 <div class="drop_zone">
  <p>Drop Here</p>
   </div>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="yourregularuploadformId">
   <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

jQuery and javascript code:

```
function handleFiles(droppedFiles) {
var uploadFormData = new FormData($("#yourregularuploadformId")[0]);
    if(droppedFiles.length > 0) { // checks if any files were dropped
    for(var f = 0; f < droppedFiles.length; f++) { // for-loop for each file dropped
     alert(droppedFiles[f]['name']);
        uploadFormData.append("files[]",droppedFiles[f]);  // adding every        file to the form so you could upload multiple files
    }
}

// the final ajax call
alert(uploadFormData);
   $.ajax({
    url : "try.php", // use your target
    type : "POST",
    data : uploadFormData,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(ret) {
             alert(ret);
    }
   });
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
//alert("im in");
$('.drop_zone').bind("dragenter", function(e) { 
  // $('#StatusDrag').html('Drop The files Here...');
});
$('.drop_zone').bind("dragleave", function(e) {
   // $('#StatusDrag').html('Drag and Drop Files Here to Share');
});
$('.drop_zone').bind("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('.drop_zone').bind("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
   // $('#dragBox, #topDiv').hide();
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    var files = dt.files;
    handleFiles(files);
});
});
```

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["files"]))
{
foreach ($_FILES["files"] as $file) 
echo $file['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i can't upload multiple files everytime i try to upload it i get and error 5 times since i have only uploaded 2 files only still i get error 5 times saying that undefined index:'name' in try.php....